# python get rid of unicode and `\r\n` characters

Tags: python

I want to get rid `\r\n' characters in my string to do so, I tried this :

```
s1.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, u"\n\r")))
    lists1=[]
    lists1.append(s1)
    print lists1
```

I received this:

```
[u'\r\nFoo\r\nBar, FooBar']
```

How can I get rid of `\r\n` characters in my string ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of the unicode"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str()` and `replace()` to remove both `u` and `\r\n`:

```
In [21]: strs = u'\r\nFoo\r\nBar'

In [22]: str(strs).replace("\r\n","")
Out[22]: 'FooBar'
```

or just `replace()` to get rid of only `\r\n`:

```
In [23]: strs.replace("\r\n","")
Out[23]: u'FooBar'
```

Comment: I don't think you need to convert to a string first.

Comment: OP said he wants to get rid of the `u` as well.(in the title)

Comment: Oh I see. But... that actually involves an encoding, which is done implicitly here to 'ascii'. But the OP started with a unicode literal.

Comment: Thanks, what about the case that '\n' and '\r' separate in the text. In this case, how to get rid of '\n' and '\r' ?

Comment: @JohnSmith then you need two replace call like this : `strs.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
`

Answer (score 1):

```
cleaned = u"".join([line.strip() for line in u'\r\nFoo\r\nBar, FooBar'.split("\r\n")])
```

or just use `replace()`:

```
cleaned = u'\r\nFoo\r\nBar, FooBar'.replace("\r\n", "")
```

Comment: Thanks, what about the case that '\n' and '\r' separate in the string. In this case, how to get rid of '\n' and '\r' ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
'this is my string\r\nand here it continues'.replace('\r\n', '')
```